# How to set up GEKKO for parameter estimation from multiple sets of data and initial conditions?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I'm new to Gekko. Following @John Hedengren documentation and answers to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852474/parameters-estimation-with-multiple-data-sets-using-gekko) from @jmiguel, I'm trying to estimate two parameters of a biological reaction described as follows:

- R+L<-->Y
- R+I<-->X

This result in a system of five coupled differential equations:

- dX/dt=k1*R(t)*L(t)-k2*Y(t)
- dY/dt=k3*R(t)*I(t)-k4*X(t)
- dR/dt=k2*Y(t)-k1*R(t)*L(t)+k4*X(t)-k3*R(t)*I(t)
- dL/dt=k2*Y(t)-k1*R(t)*L(t)
- dI/dt=k4*X(t)-k3*R(t)*I(t)
  where k1 and k2 are knowed constants and k3,k4 are the two parameters that I want to estimate.

To estimate I have 4 sets of 'Y' data that correspond to four different initial concentrations of 'I' measured at the same times. I want to use all this data to estimate k3 and k4, but I don't know how to implement the four data sets together.

Here is my try:

```
#Modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import math as math
import pandas as pd

#4 sets of data for Y with same tame and differente concentrations
texp=[0,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,2,2.77,3.55,4.32,5.1,5.87,6.65,7.42,8.2,8.97,13.92,18.92,23.92,28.92,33.92,38.92,43.92,48.92,53.92,58.92,63.92,68.92,83.9,98.9,113.9,128.9,143.9,158.9,173.9,188.9,203.9,218.9,233.9,248.9]
yexp=[[0,134.0972365,101.6778993,95.40580822,77.46417317,97.38426357,94.95124669,92.01743212,103.1524256,101.6335581,100.8064012,97.36957339,98.54218566,105.1649371,100.7135276,91.76116765,98.50303784,99.09282871,101.2884698,98.16682444,98.95862295,100.1781904,97.67407619,98.05420149,101.7811854,99.65343296,99.35574195,101.5667478,97.8827634,99.21928788,100.2506635,103.3401759,97.77635857,95.59188964,97.63152972,98.68365575,97.94605393,94.40686956,101.4638065],
      [0,52.8368317,60.63226219,57.1596205,77.40224428,76.59558061,83.08583996,92.71540378,92.74825352,97.77466238,87.90927062,91.55955552,93.40910581,97.38680721,98.68892712,96.28587494,97.24139983,99.14913748,97.05786666,99.52031603,98.25378711,98.45507123,98.48665412,96.58596306,98.49718892,97.03260859,97.78876552,96.96130531,96.16927889,99.05385817,99.81984318,98.34275219,97.06707695,98.13554762,96.40027439,97.02992383,97.92157304,97.45153492,100.7723151],
      [0,6.651270535,-0.894974357,28.70354922,41.78345531,28.39710692,38.44803531,52.61165239,31.33900251,47.7098898,46.13716223,60.80324347,63.06296709,61.14672153,62.56302041,73.57634262,80.68134402,84.09161715,86.42168805,83.62885021,82.69730894,87.38430639,92.26394519,87.78013332,85.96624579,87.84265572,85.32430667,87.74945544,87.06258236,88.05326643,86.29714124,90.465153,86.36689116,81.69960378,87.69867171,82.08550027,85.6811316,88.07994935,87.69384792],
      [0,21.00084301,-54.20967226,-12.0118567,-25.27198718,-1.764831016,10.29814076,-5.340599221,6.988265971,9.56252586,-3.705303123,1.063813346,12.32611118,7.763248428,9.074028389,20.60003402,22.1001936,23.13229101,27.31536018,25.00455108,31.70315201,35.10288809,38.0816535,35.30253723,36.81655545,36.11171691,41.57221204,42.47852506,46.28315167,42.66070948,44.73318881,37.36241544,39.69557981,38.71667563,37.49757832,42.35943236,41.68017195,44.91883581,47.80088108]]

#Initial condition
Y0=[0,0,0,0]
X0=[0,0,0,0]
R0=[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]
L0=[30e-9,30e-9,30e-9,30e-9]
I0=[1000e-9,100e-9,10e-9,1e-9]#One initial condicion for I, one per dataset

#Combine the data in the same dataframe
#···Define each dataset in a dataframe
df1=pd.DataFrame({'time':texp,'y1':yexp[0]})
df1.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df2=pd.DataFrame({'time':texp,'y2':yexp[1]})
df2.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df3=pd.DataFrame({'time':texp,'y3':yexp[2]})
df3.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df4=pd.DataFrame({'time':texp,'y4':yexp[3]})
df4.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#···Merge dataframes
data=df1.join(df2,how='outer').join(df3,how='outer').join(df4,how='outer')

#Model
m=GEKKO(remote=False)
t=m.time=data.index

#···Arrays to store observed values of Y
Ym=m.Array(m.Param,4)
Ym[0].value=data['y1'].values
Ym[1].value=data['y2'].values
Ym[2].value=data['y3'].values
Ym[3].value=data['y4'].values

#···Variable for differential equations
Y=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
X=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
R=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
L=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
I=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
#···Initial values
for j in range(4):
    Y[j].value=Y0[j]
    X[j].value=X0[j]
    R[j].value=R0[j]
    L[j].value=L0[j]
    I[j].value=I0[j]

#···Parameters
#····Fixed
k1=m.Const(value=3.58e6)
k2=m.Const(value=1.25e-1)
#····Variable
k3=m.FV(value=1e8,lb=10e1,ub=10e10)
k3.STATUS=1
k4=m.FV(value=1e-2,lb=10e-5,ub=10e3)
k4.STATUS=1

#···Define reaction rate variables
r1=m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=0)
r2=m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=0)
r3=m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=0)
r4=m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=0)

#···Model equations
for k in range(4):
    #····Rate equations
    m.Equation(r1[k] == k1*R[k]*L[k])
    m.Equation(r2[k] == k2*Y[k])
    m.Equation(r3[k] == k3*R[k]*I[k])
    m.Equation(r4[k] == k4*X[k])
    #····Differential species balances
    m.Equation(X[k].dt() == -r4[k]+r3[k])
    m.Equation(Y[k].dt() == -r2[k]+r1[k])
    m.Equation(R[k].dt() == r2[k]-r1[k]+r4[k]-r3[k])
    m.Equation(L[k].dt() == r2[k]-r1[k])
    m.Equation(I[k].dt() == r4[k]-r3[k])
    #····Minimization objective functions
    m.Minimize((Y[k]-Ym[k])**2)
    
#···Solver
m.options.IMODE=2
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.options.MAX_ITER=10000
m.options.NODES=3
#m.options. COLDSTART=2
m.solve()

print(k3.value[0], k4.value[0])
labels=['X0','X1','X2','X3','Y0','Y1','Y2','Y3','R0','R1','R2','R3','L0','L1','L2','L3','I0','I1','I2','I3','yexp0','yexp1','yexp2','yexp3']
datas=[X[0].value,X[1].value,X[2].value,X[3].value,Y[0].value,Y[1].value,Y[2].value,Y[3].value,R[0].value,R[1].value,
      R[2].value,R[3].value,L[0].value,L[1].value,L[2].value,L[3].value,I[0].value,I[1].value,I[2].value,I[3].value,
      yexp[0],yexp[1],yexp[2],yexp[3]]
plt.figure(1,figsize=(24,10))
for f in range(24):
    plt.subplot(6,4,f+1)
    plt.plot(t,datas[f],label=labels[f])
    plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And here is the answer:

> Warning: model time only used for dynamic modes (IMODE>3)
> ----------------------------------------------------------------
> APMonitor, Version 1.0.0
> APMonitor Optimization Suite
> ----------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ```
>  --------- APM Model Size ------------
>  Each time step contains
>    Objects      :  0
>    Constants    :  2
>    Variables    :  42
>    Intermediates:  0
>    Connections  :  0
>    Equations    :  40
>    Residuals    :  40
>  
>  Number of state variables:    1406
>  Number of total equations: -  1404
>  Number of slack variables: -  0
>  ---------------------------------------
>  Degrees of freedom       :    2
>  
>  **********************************************
>  Model Parameter Estimation with Interior Point Solver
>  **********************************************
>   
>   
>  Info: Exact Hessian
>
> ******************************************************************************
> This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
>  Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
>          For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
> ******************************************************************************
>
> This is Ipopt version 3.10.2, running with linear solver mumps.
>
> Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:     3744
> Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
> Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:      936
>
> MUMPS returned INFO(1) = -9 and requires more memory, reallocating.  Attempt 1
>   Increasing icntl[13] from 1000 to 2000.
> MUMPS returned INFO(1) = -9 and requires more memory, reallocating.  Attempt 2
>   Increasing icntl[13] from 2000 to 4000.
> Total number of variables............................:     1406
>                      variables with only lower bounds:     1404
>                 variables with lower and upper bounds:        2
>                      variables with only upper bounds:        0
> Total number of equality constraints.................:     1404
> Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
>         inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
>    inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
>         inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0
>
> iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
>    0 9.4857890e+005 5.00e+005 1.01e+002   0.0 0.00e+000    -  0.00e+000 0.00e+000   0
>    1 9.4878851e+005 1.24e+005 2.38e+000  -5.1 1.00e+000    -  2.40e-001 9.84e-001h  1
>    2 9.4879369e+005 3.17e+004 6.49e+001  -1.3 2.66e-001   2.0 9.90e-001 9.90e-001h  1
>    3 9.4879397e+005 4.07e+002 2.23e+001  -7.0 2.93e-001   1.5 7.05e-001 7.04e-001h  1
>    4 9.4879401e+005 7.00e+000 1.48e+001  -7.5 7.83e-002    -  3.59e-001 3.55e-001h  1
> ...
> Number of Iterations....: 107
>
>                                    (scaled)                 (unscaled)
> Objective...............:  1.4048811068946009e+003   3.7678134809125418e+003
> Dual infeasibility......:  8.5533874233035452e-007   2.2939712323577221e-006
> Constraint violation....:  4.2404425129693523e-009   7.5660587128822954e-007
> Complementarity.........:  7.3513361195303513e-010   1.9715877164233078e-009
> Overall NLP error.......:  8.5533874233035452e-007   2.2939712323577221e-006
>
>
> Number of objective function evaluations             = 108
> Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 108
> Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 108
> Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
> Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 108
> Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
> Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 107
> Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      4.992
> Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      1.235
>
> EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
>
>  The solution was found.
>
>  The final value of the objective function is  3767.8134809125418
>  
>  ---------------------------------------------------
>  Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
>  Solution time  :  6.2372000000000005 sec
>  Objective      :  3767.8134828332963
>  Successful solution
>  ---------------------------------------------------
>  
>
> k3=4563.4117885 k4=1732.3167918
> ```

To check that it is working, I have solved this using an simplified equivalent system of equations, solving it symbolically and doing a non-linear regression using curve_fit from scipy and the results are very different.

I suspect that I am not getting the data entered correctly in the model. Moreover, maybe the model is not well built at all.

Thank you for your time reading my question and for any help/ideas you may have!

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `IMODE=5` to solve the dynamic version of the problem instead of `IMODE=2` that considers each data point to be at steady-state.

```py
m.options.IMODE=5
```

Although the problem solves successfully, the results do not look correct because the predicted `y` does not match the measured `ym`.

[image: results]

```py
#Modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import math as math
import pandas as pd

texp=[0.0001,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,2,2.77,3.55,4.32,5.1,5.87,6.65,7.42,\
      8.2,8.97,13.92,18.92,23.92,28.92,33.92,38.92,43.92,48.92,53.92,\
      58.92,63.92,68.92,83.9,98.9,113.9,128.9,143.9,158.9,173.9,188.9,\
      203.9,218.9,233.9,248.9]
yexp=[[0,134.0972365,101.6778993,95.40580822,77.46417317,97.38426357,\
       94.95124669,92.01743212,103.1524256,101.6335581,100.8064012,97.36957339,\
       98.54218566,105.1649371,100.7135276,91.76116765,98.50303784,99.09282871,\
       101.2884698,98.16682444,98.95862295,100.1781904,97.67407619,98.05420149,\
       101.7811854,99.65343296,99.35574195,101.5667478,97.8827634,99.21928788,\
       100.2506635,103.3401759,97.77635857,95.59188964,97.63152972,98.68365575,\
       97.94605393,94.40686956,101.4638065], \
      [0,52.8368317,60.63226219,57.1596205,77.40224428,76.59558061,83.08583996,\
       92.71540378,92.74825352,97.77466238,87.90927062,91.55955552,93.40910581,\
       97.38680721,98.68892712,96.28587494,97.24139983,99.14913748,97.05786666,\
       99.52031603,98.25378711,98.45507123,98.48665412,96.58596306,98.49718892,\
       97.03260859,97.78876552,96.96130531,96.16927889,99.05385817,99.81984318,\
       98.34275219,97.06707695,98.13554762,96.40027439,97.02992383,97.92157304,\
       97.45153492,100.7723151], \
      [0,6.651270535,-0.894974357,28.70354922,41.78345531,28.39710692,\
       38.44803531,52.61165239,31.33900251,47.7098898,46.13716223,60.80324347,\
       63.06296709,61.14672153,62.56302041,73.57634262,80.68134402,84.09161715,\
       86.42168805,83.62885021,82.69730894,87.38430639,92.26394519,87.78013332,\
       85.96624579,87.84265572,85.32430667,87.74945544,87.06258236,88.05326643,\
       86.29714124,90.465153,86.36689116,81.69960378,87.69867171,82.08550027,\
       85.6811316,88.07994935,87.69384792], \
      [0,21.00084301,-54.20967226,-12.0118567,-25.27198718,-1.764831016,\
       10.29814076,-5.340599221,6.988265971,9.56252586,-3.705303123,\
       1.063813346,12.32611118,7.763248428,9.074028389,20.60003402,\
       22.1001936,23.13229101,27.31536018,25.00455108,31.70315201,\
       35.10288809,38.0816535,35.30253723,36.81655545,36.11171691,\
       41.57221204,42.47852506,46.28315167,42.66070948,44.73318881,\
       37.36241544,39.69557981,38.71667563,37.49757832,42.35943236,\
       41.68017195,44.91883581,47.80088108]]

#Initial condition
Y0=[0,0,0,0]
X0=[0,0,0,0]
R0=[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]
L0=[30e-9,30e-9,30e-9,30e-9]
I0=[1000e-9,100e-9,10e-9,1e-9] #One initial condicion for I, one per dataset

#Combine the data in the same dataframe
#···Define each dataset in a dataframe
df1=pd.DataFrame({'time':texp,'y1':yexp[0]})
df1.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df2=pd.DataFrame({'time':texp,'y2':yexp[1]})
df2.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df3=pd.DataFrame({'time':texp,'y3':yexp[2]})
df3.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df4=pd.DataFrame({'time':texp,'y4':yexp[3]})
df4.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#···Merge dataframes
data=df1.join(df2,how='outer').join(df3,how='outer').join(df4,how='outer')

#Model
m=GEKKO(remote=True)
t=m.time=data.index

#···Arrays to store observed values of Y
Ym=m.Array(m.Param,4)
Ym[0].value=data['y1'].values
Ym[1].value=data['y2'].values
Ym[2].value=data['y3'].values
Ym[3].value=data['y4'].values

#···Variable for differential equations
Y=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
X=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
R=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
L=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
I=m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0)
#···Initial values
for j in range(4):
    Y[j].value=Y0[j]
    X[j].value=X0[j]
    R[j].value=R0[j]
    L[j].value=L0[j]
    I[j].value=I0[j]

#···Parameters
#····Fixed
k1=m.Const(value=3.58e-6)
k2=m.Const(value=1.25e-1)
#····Variable
k3=m.FV(value=1e8,lb=10e1,ub=10e10)
k3.STATUS=1
k4=m.FV(value=1e-2,lb=10e-5,ub=10e3)
k4.STATUS=1

#···Define reaction rate variables
r1=m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=0)
r2=m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=0)
r3=m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=0)
r4=m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=0)

#···Model equations
for k in range(4):
    #····Rate equations
    m.Equation(r1[k] == k1*R[k]*L[k])
    m.Equation(r2[k] == k2*Y[k])
    m.Equation(r3[k] == k3*R[k]*I[k])
    m.Equation(r4[k] == k4*X[k])
    #····Differential species balances
    m.Equation(X[k].dt() == -r4[k]+r3[k])
    m.Equation(Y[k].dt() == -r2[k]+r1[k])
    m.Equation(R[k].dt() == r2[k]-r1[k]+r4[k]-r3[k])
    m.Equation(L[k].dt() == r2[k]-r1[k])
    m.Equation(I[k].dt() == r4[k]-r3[k])
    #····Minimization objective functions
    m.Minimize((Y[k]-Ym[k])**2)
    
#···Solver
m.options.IMODE=5
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.options.MAX_ITER=10000
m.options.NODES=3
#m.options. COLDSTART=2
m.solve()

print(k3.value[0], k4.value[0])
labels=['X0','X1','X2','X3','Y0','Y1','Y2','Y3',\
        'R0','R1','R2','R3','L0','L1','L2','L3',\
        'I0','I1','I2','I3','yexp0','yexp1','yexp2','yexp3']
datas=[X[0].value,X[1].value,X[2].value,X[3].value,\
       Y[0].value,Y[1].value,Y[2].value,Y[3].value,\
       R[0].value,R[1].value,
      R[2].value,R[3].value,L[0].value,L[1].value,\
      L[2].value,L[3].value,I[0].value,I[1].value,\
      I[2].value,I[3].value,
      yexp[0],yexp[1],yexp[2],yexp[3]]
plt.figure(1,figsize=(24,10))
for f in range(24):
    plt.subplot(6,4,f+1)
    plt.plot(t,datas[f],label=labels[f])
    plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If there is another solution for comparison, then try setting the values of `k3` and `k4` with `STATUS=0` to ensure that the simulation equations are correct. There are some other suggestions in your earlier post: [Parameters estimation with GEKKO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72273663/parameters-estimation-with-gekko)

Comment: Thank you @John Hedengren for your answers. Are here the four samples of Y data fitting together in the optimization?

Comment: Yes, all four sets of data are used to find the parameter values `k3` and `k4`.